# TWRequest from a dictionary in a tableView Cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, twrequest

I am trying to propagate a table view with a custom cell with the results of a TWRequest with no luck. I am trying to store the tweets in a dictionary object then calling an ObjectAtKey request and putting into a string. Here is my code - any help would be appreciated. Thanks -

```
-(void)fetchTweets
{
    // Do a simple search, using the Twitter API
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                         @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=iOS%205&rpp=5&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"] 
                                             parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    // Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
        {
            // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
            // Move the response into a dictionary and print
            NSError *error;        
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);                           
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }  


    NSString *tweetText = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSArray *tweetComponents = [tweetText componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; 


    cell.Header.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.Details.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.Date.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:2];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this please......?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an NSMutableArray of the tweets from the Twitter response. 
Each tweet being a separate object.

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *tweet in dict)
{
     [resultArray addObject:tweet];
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the object based on the row of the table, something like

`TweetResult *tweetResult [resultArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However TweetResult *tweetResult returns errors it says that tweetResult is undeclared - do I need to put this in my.h file? If so what exactly is TweetResult, is it an array or a dictionary? Thanks

Comment: Ah yeh so TweetResult is an example of an NSObject you should create yourself. That will have properties like Tweet, Username, Realname etc...

Comment: Ok great, so presumably I can access it with objectForKey as I would a dictionary to extract the "text" component, is that correct? Thanks